# Export data in the order it was added - PowerShell Export-Csv

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I have this code

```
function get-data()
{
   $rec=[PSCustomObject]@()
   $DLGP = "" | Select "Name","Grade","Score"

   foreach($record in $data) 
   {
       $DLGP.Name=$record.name
       $DLGP.Grade=$record.grade
       $DLGP.Score=$record.score
       $rec += $DLGP
   }
   return $rec
}

$mydata=get-data
$mydata | Export-Csv -Path $outputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is, the data is not exported in the order that I have added it to $rec

How can I get it exported in the order it was added?

Comment: By default a `[PSCustomObject]` is unordered. Since Powerschell version 4 or 5 I guess there are ordered custom objects. Just add `[ordered]` in front of the `[PSCutomObject]` ....  like this: `[ordered][PSCostomObject]`

Comment: @Olaf: A `[pscustomobject]` instance has always enumerated its properties in _definition order_. It is _hashtables_ whose entries are enumerated in no guaranteed order; PSv3 introduced `[ordered] @{ ... }` to allow defining ordered hashtable literals whose entries are enumerated in definition order too and also enabled casting hashtable literals to `[pscustomobject]`, in which case `[ordered]` is _implied_ - in PSv2- such casts simply didn't work at all (were no-ops). However, the OP's issue is unrelated to member ordering - see my answer. `[ordered]` only ever works  before `@{ ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without even using your function, a simple

```
$mydata = $data | select Name,Grade,Score
```

would yield the desired result.

Your function is IMO overcomplicated:

```
$Data = @"
Name,Grade,Score,Dummy
Anthoni,A,10,v
Brandon,B,20,x
Christian,C,30,y
David,D,40,z
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

function get-data() {
   ForEach($record in $data) {
       [PSCustomObject]@{
           Name =$record.name
           Grade=$record.grade
           Score=$record.score
       }
   }
}

$mydata=get-data
$mydata # | Export-Csv -Path $outputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Returns here the pretty same order:

```
Name      Grade Score
----      ----- -----
Anthoni   A     10
Brandon   B     20
Christian C     30
David     D     40
```

Answer (score 2):

**[LotPings' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51112667/45375) provides effective solutions.**

As for **what you tried**:

By constructing only a *single* `[pscustomobject]` instance *outside the loop*:

```
$DLGP = "" | Select "Name","Grade","Score"
```

and then only updating that one instance's properties in each loop iteration:

```
$DLGP.Name=$record.name
# ....
```

you **effectively added the very same `[pscustomobject]` instance multiple times to the result array** instead of creating a distinct object in each iteration.

Since the same object was being updated repeatedly, that object ended up having the properties of the *last* object in the input collection, `$data`.

As an aside:

`[PSCustomObject] @()` is effectively the same as `@()`: the `[PSCustomObject]` is *ignored* and you get an `[object[]]` array.

To type the array as one containing `[PSCustomObject]` instances, you'd have to use an *array*-typed cast: `[PSCustomObject[]] @()`.

However, given that instances of *any* type can be cast to `[PSCustomObject]` - which is really the same as `[psobject]` - this offers no type safety and no performance benefit.

Also, since your `$rec` variable isn't type-constrained (it is defined as `$rec = [<type>] ...` rather than `[<type>] $rec = ...`) and you're using `+=` to "add to" the array (which invariably requires creation of a *new instance* behind the scenes), `$rec` would revert to an `[object[]]` array after the first `+=` operation.